# How to identify this div tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping UpWork job proposals and have located the div tag which contains all job postings, it's opening tag looks like this:

```
<div data-job-list-responsive="" data-ng-if="isInitialRequestComplete && !(isSavedJobsTabAvailable && isSavedJobsTab())" class="ng-scope">
#bunch of section objects for each job proposal 
<\div>
```

I am just wondering how would I go about identifying this tag? For example Beautiful Soup allows to search by id like:

`results = soup.find(id='ResultsContainer')`

but I can't deliminate any defining characteristic of the above div tag apart from class='ng-scope' but far too many elements on the page belong to that class to make it meaningful.

I think its something to do with the "data-job-list-responsive" title but unsure what element of the div tag this would be?

Comment: this looks to be angular js. Chances are the data is embeded in json format in a script tag or access directly from an api request. Can you share the url and I can take a look?

Comment: thank you for replying! the url is: https://www.upwork.com/ab/jobs/search/?proposals=0-4&q=machine%20learning&sort=recency&user_location_match=2 and all I am looking for is how to retrieve all job postings from that url! thanks :)

Comment: I'm afraid this one might not be able to be scraped (or at least will require a bit more effort than what I'm willing to put in). the site blocks automated ways to web scrape. you'll get a few pages into it, but then you'll get blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for all the `div`-tags with an `data-job-list-responsive` attribute with empty value `""` and an `data-ng-if` attribute with value `"isInitialRequestComplete && !(isSavedJobsTabAvailable && isSavedJobsTab())"`:

```py
soup = BeautfulSoup(your_html)
soup.find_all("div", {"data-job-list-responsive" : "", "data-ng-if" : "isInitialRequestComplete && !(isSavedJobsTabAvailable && isSavedJobsTab())"})
```

However, it is quite likely that that web page content is dynamically created by javascript. You can easily verify it by disabling javascript, reloading the page and checking if the required content is still there.